# cakephp 3 sql query builder error

Tags: sql, cakephp, mariadb

Here is my query:

```
$today = date('m/d/y');

$todays=$this->Tasks->find()
            ->where(['user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
            ->andWhere(["DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(due_date, '%m/%d/%Y'),'%m/%d/%y')"=>$today]);


    $this->set('todays',$todays);
```

Here is the error im getting:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>   ''05/16/17')' at line 1.

dont know why or how to fix this?

here is the query

```
SELECT
    Tasks.id AS `Tasks__id`,
    Tasks.user_id AS `Tasks__user_id`,
    Tasks.title AS `Tasks__title`,
    Tasks.body AS `Tasks__body`,
    Tasks.due_date AS `Tasks__due_date`,
    Tasks.complete AS `Tasks__complete`,
    Tasks.created AS `Tasks__created`,
    Tasks.modified AS `Tasks__modified` 
FROM
    tasks Tasks 
WHERE
    (
        user_id = :c0 
        AND
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(due_date, '%m/%d/%y'), '%m/%d/%y') :c1
    )
```

Comment: What is the type and format of due_date column?

Comment: due_date is a string '05/16/2017'

Comment: Whenever encountering such errors, please always show the generated query, even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP - thanks!

Comment: @AaronMichaelTempleton update your question with the query.

Comment: use the date datatype always for storing dates in mariadb. Then use $today = date ("Y-m-d"); Then you can simply compare them without converting and formatting.

Comment: Another case of 3rd party software getting in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use capital Y instead of small y while calling the date () function. refer to 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
for details of formatting dates.

But,
use the date datatype always for storing dates in mariadb. Then use $today = date ("Y-m-d"); Then you can simply compare them without converting and formatting

Answer (score 0):

Since you said in your question's comments that your column is a string containing dates in `d/m/Y` format, you just need to compare two strings in your query.

```
$today = date('m/d/Y');

$todays = $this->Tasks->find()
            ->where(['user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
            ->where(['due_date' => $today]);

$this->set('todays', $todays);
```

> I recommend you to create a migration to change `due_date` column type
>   to `date`.

Comment: Until you change both `due_date` and `$today`, you are likely to get into trouble with leading zeros.